# Amazon Intrinsic function to get all the VPC from an account for cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

For a CloudFormation script, I need a function that will get all the available VPC IDs from the account that is executing that script.

I would like the user to select from the list of existing VPCs, in the same way that you have for example when launching an EC2 instance (networking combobox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [AWS-specific parameter type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types), `AWS::EC2::VPC::Id`:

> For AWS-specific parameter types, template users must specify existing AWS values that are in their account.

Example:

```
Parameters: 
  VPCId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
```